# Elevated PowerShell instance no longer working on Win 11

Tags: powershell, windows-11, administrator

Win 11 22H2

For awhile now, I have used a scheduled task with the flag "`Run with highest privileges`" checked, to run some PowerShell scripts (Method 1).:

[image]

This is the same as starting a PowerShell shortcut to the script and right clicking and selecting "`Run as administrator`" (Method 2):

[image]

In this script in particular, I am setting some services in services.msc to Manual / Automatic with the following:

```
Set-Service –Name $service –StartupType Manual
```

What is happening now, is that this is **not** working using the 2 methods described above. It's as if the session for administrator isn't even for my account anymore. It doesn't throw any errors complaining about insufficient access, it runs as if it did indeed set the service to Manual, but when checking services.msc, nothing actually was changed.

The only way I can get this to work is to change the command to run from cmd.exe by adding to my script:

```
cmd.exe /c "sc config $service start= demand"
```

or, manually opening a PowerShell window as admin on my device, and running the code from there by pasting it in or navigating to the directory to run the script. This use to work fine back on Win10 / early Win11. I'm not sure what changed.

I am on a fresh install of Windows 11 as of 1 month ago.

Path for shortcut and scheduled task:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Users\talor\OneDrive\Scripts\set-services-to-manual-and-stopped.ps1"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your triggers are but change the `Change User or Group` to be `SYSTEM` and then check the option `Run whether use is logged on or not` and you can leave all your other options to same. Now manually run the task and check the properties of the service afterwards. Point the Script/Program in `Actions` to be full path to the PowerShell.exe file, and have the `Arguments` be `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Users\talor\OneDrive\Scripts\set-services-to-manual-and-stopped.ps1"` from the Task Scheduler. Maybe you will not need to run as `SYSTEM` changing just those, test both ways.

Comment: Tried all of those already except the SYSTEM thing. That didn't work. I believe this has more to do with the console window being ran and it's securities. It seems like a powershell terminal running as admin is completely different than a powershell window opening from a shortcut (which is how scheduled tasks opens it too).

Comment: I'm not sure about the shortcut, but move the script to `C:\Scripts` and then do those same things using that path. Furthermore, add `Start-Transcript C:\Logs\setservice.log`, run the process, then check the transcript log. I've automated this sort of thing on Windows 10 and Windows servers before using Task Scheduler so perhaps it is the shortcut, and if that is the case, don't use a shortcut, move the script to the local file system in a different folder not within a profile or onedrive mounted location, and then schedule it to run from there instead.

Comment: The only thing in the log was "Transcript started, output file is C:\Logs\setservice.log". Moving the script to C:\Scripts did not change anything either. Sorry.

Comment: Can you explain how exactly you are setting the `$service` variable in your script? That may hold the key, it should work the same with Windows 11 as Windows 10 but I have not tried with Windows 11 personally. From what I saw when I tested with the print spooler service and used `Set-Service –Name Spooler –StartupType Automatic` the transcript file showed only that when it worked. When I ran it and it did not work to elevate the permission, I saw errors like this in the log file: https://i.imgur.com/tn6L3nf.png. Can you see if that logic does anything different. Maybe specific to that service.

Comment: If you run the logic as `SYSTEM` though, that it like Linus root user so it has full permissions to everything. You said you tried all except that, so wanted to see what you get there if/when you do try. It's easy to change and change back as listed in my original comment so it's easy to test that. But yes, test with a different service like the spooler perhaps with and without the transcript logging. Maybe it is service specific to the service(s) with the issues but I'd test more.

Comment: I found the issue. Somehow this character was changed? Unsure how since this script was untouched since forever. The " - " character was different and was throwing an error: `"The character U+2013 "–" could be confused with the character U+002d "-", which is more common in source code. Adjust settings"`. See here: https://i.imgur.com/rrg6ZR0.png. I discovered this because the log was showing the command running as: `Set-Service â€“Name $service â€“StartupType Manual`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. Somehow this character was changed. Unsure how since this script was untouched since forever. The " - " character was different and was throwing an error:
"The character U+2013 "–" could be confused with the character U+002d "-", which is more common in source code. Adjust settings".

See here:
[image]

I discovered this because the log was showing the command running as:
`Set-Service â€“Name $service â€“StartupType Manual`